# How to access a variable that's inside a static fragment, from outside this fragment?

Tags: java, android

I'm on Android. I need to access a variable that's inside a static fragment called `SettingsFragment` (which itself is inside an activity called `SettingsActivity`) from another Fragment called `MyDialogFragment`.

Here is the SettingsFragment. The variable I want to access is called `drawable`:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

        //This is the variable I want to access inside MyDialogFragment
        public Drawable drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.hohol);

        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisplayPreferenceDialog(Preference preference) {
            if (preference instanceof MyDialogFragment) {
                MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
                myDialogFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "My Dialog");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the MyDialogFragment:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder builder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = requireActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);
        builder.setView(view);

        Drawable drawable = SettingsActivity.SettingsFragment.drawable; //Doesn't work

        return dialog;
    }

}
```

I tried to get the drawable inside of the dialog fragment but I can't figure out how. Important thing to note is that I cannot make the drawable variable inside `SettingsFragment` a static variable because I need it to be non static.

Comment: Have the two fragments share a `ViewModel`, and put the data in that viewmodel.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't know what that means :)

Comment: @CommonsWare btw I don't know if this is important to mention or not but I am opening `MyDialogFragment` from inside `SettingsFragment`. So the current activity that's open behind `MyDialogFragment` is the SettingsActivity.

Comment: "I don't know what that means :)" -- the Jetpack `ViewModel` system has been around for five years or so. Make sure that you are learning Android app development from up-to-date resources. FWIW, I cover `ViewModel` in [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack) and [this free book](https://commonsware.com/AndExplore). It is also covered in the official documentation, such as [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel), including specifically [for sharing data between fragments](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing).

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok thanks I will try it. But before I do should I be concerned about the fact that SettingsFragment is static? Just making sure

Comment: @CommonsWare Also what if this was a Java question purely, without android. Meaning I was trying to access a variable that's inside a static inner class that happens to be called SettingsFragment from somewhere else? How would that be done?

Comment: "But before I do should I be concerned about the fact that SettingsFragment is static?" -- it is an unusual setup, but it should not cause a problem. "Also what if this was a Java question purely, without android" -- in these circumstances, that statement makes little sense to me. "How would that be done?" -- via `.drawable`. Your problem is not Java syntax. Your problem is that one fragment should not hold a reference to a peer fragment, and that is an Android architecture issue, not a Java language issue.